# How to open and close every link in a file(Selenium\Java)

Tags: java, selenium

Selenium\Java

```
public void CheckLanding() throws IOException {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 3000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("My path to file"));
    String str;

    ArrayList<String> listLanding = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((str = reader.readLine()) != null ){
        if(!str.isEmpty()){
            listLanding.add(str);
            System.out.println(str);
        }}
    String[] stringArr = listLanding.toArray(new String[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++){
        driver.get();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I want to open and close array [0]. And then I passed one test for all links

Comment: can you please explain what do you intend to do?

Comment: Oh sure.
I have 100 links to landing pages, and on each link there is a check that is identical for each link, I want to take a list, make an array, then through a loop, open each link and run one test for each link. the browser is closed. And so in a circle

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find a nice and clean solution using the `webdrivermanager` for browser handling, `JUnit` with `DataProvider` library.

**Maven libraries**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-dataprovider</artifactId>
   <version>1.10.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.12</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
   <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java Code**

```
import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.DataProvider;
import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.DataProviderRunner;
import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.UseDataProvider;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@RunWith(DataProviderRunner.class)
public class OpenLink {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws IOException {
//        afterclass code
    }

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] webLinksDataProvider() {
        List<String> webLinksProvider = new ArrayList<>();
        webLinksProvider.add("https://www.google.com");
        webLinksProvider.add("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
        webLinksProvider.add("https://www.facebook.com");
        webLinksProvider.add("https://www.instagram.com");
//        parse your file and add the urls to the webLinkProvider

//        convert your list you Object[][]
        Object[][] objArray = new Object[webLinksProvider.size()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < webLinksProvider.size(); i++) {
            objArray[i] = new Object[1];
            objArray[i][0] = webLinksProvider.get(i);
        }

        return objArray;
    }

    @Test
    @UseDataProvider("webLinksDataProvider")
    public void checkWebLinks(String webLink) {
        driver.get(webLink);
        //do your asserations
    }
}
```